# auto fit height of iframe/object anyway (CORS considired)

Tags: javascript, html, object, iframe

I am trying to have iframe or object that comes from www.frames.mysite.com/x.html
into other pages in other subdomain or even other websites. but I can't fix up the autofit I did something before and it was fine but now it's not working

```
function resizeIframe(id){

    //id is the iframe innerside box 
    // #ssbox is the parent of iframe
    var heightx=$('#'+id).contents().height();  //box inside iframe height
    $('#ssbox').height(heightx); // parent box height
    $('#'+id).css('height',heightx)
}
```

but now its a origin problem, I tried object and i tried lots of other things, is there anyway that i can include a outside page into another page with a dynamic size like facebook comment system or other web plugins.

and is there any other way that i can draw this html page which is dynamic actually into other pages with different data. i have full access to the server apache is there anything i should do in apache/php or anything?

i found a class in javascript to do that but that one kills users RAM as it's reloading the page every 300ms.

i was thinking is there anyways that i can send the height size of the iframe page from iframe page to parent page of that iframe so javascript can fit the size?

and i need this in pure javascript please if possible.